# Printing an array of strings during a loop

Tags: c, arrays, function, struct, typedef

Writing a function that uses a loop to display a small chart of "names" "e1" "e2" "e3" "e4" "avg" and "grade". In the function I'm having trouble printing the elements stored in the "names" array.

This is the function in its entirety:

```
void display(stuff *everything)
{    
int q = 0;

printf("\n\n Name \t\t E1 \t E2 \t E3 \t E4 \t Avg \t Grade");
for(q=0; q<13; q++)
{
printf("\n %s \t %d \t %d \t %d \t %d \t %.2f \t %c",
everything[q].names[q],
everything[q].scores[0],
everything[q].scores[1],
everything[q].scores[2],
everything[q].scores[3],
everything[q].average,
everything[q].letter);
}
return;
}
```

Everything is from this:

```
typedef struct structure
{
char names[20];
int scores[4];
float average;
char letter;
} stuff;
```

Once you're in Main;

```
stuff everything[13];
int i=0;
int j=0;
int a=0;
FILE *student, *score;
student = fopen("student.dat", "r");
score = fopen("scores.dat", "r");
```

Names is populated like this:

```
for(a=0; a<13; a++)
{
 fscanf(student, "%s", &everything[a].names[a]);
}
fclose(student);
```

And this is the function call:

```
display(everything);
```

It compiles fine, but when running it, I get a segmentation fault. After some testing I more or less figured out that it comes from the %s in the function and I'm not sure how to fix it. Help?

Comment: This line looks suspicious `fscanf(student, "%s", &everything[a].names[a]);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should modify the reading code as follows:

```
for(a=0; a<13; a++)
{
    fscanf(student, "%19s", everything[a].names);
}
fclose(student);
```

"names" is a character array. It can hold a string. When calling scanf, you do not need to use an ampersand, because arrays "decay" to pointers when passed to functions. Adding a subscript [a] was a mistake, too. Same applies to printing as well.

Separately note the format string in scanf: I added 19 to avoid overflowing the 20-character buffer (you need an extra character for null termination).

Answer (score 0):

`everything[q].names[q]` should be `everything[q].names`, because the purpose is to write the string (for which `printf()` needs the address of the `names` string), rather than the string pointed at by the value of the `q`th letter of the string.